# Successfully opened test-network but deploying chaincode failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I develope on Ubuntu and going through the Fabric master version documentation. In the test network part, I successfully opened test-network and creating a channel, seems to work correctly. But when I try to start a chaincode on the channel, it goes wrong.

I run  the command as follow:

```
./network.sh deployCC
```

And it returns error as follow:

```
Error: error getting chaincode bytes: listing deps for pacakge ../chaincode/fabric/go failed: exit status 2
!!!Chaincode packing on peer0.org1 has failed!!!

ERROR!!! Deploying chaincode failed
```

May somebody tells me what's happened? Thanks for kindly help.

[image]

Following are error logs from docker.
[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you post error logs from your peer?

Comment: the log.txt is already posted above

Comment: Are you using docker? I mean your peer error logs from docker

Comment: Yes, I following the Hyperledger Fabric Doc and using docker. How can I find the peer error logs from docker?

Comment: `docker ps`
search for container named peer0.org1
`docker logs your-container-id`

Comment: I post the error logs above. Sorry, I only know to take the screenshot.

Comment: I see the error `go: unknown subcommand mod`. What version of go are you using ? try using go 1.13

Answer (score 0):

From the `go: unknown subcommand “mod”` error message, I’m guessing you’re using a very old version of go.

The script is likely trying to vendor the chaincode dependencies prior to packaging for deployment.